# Full Help Documentation not working for libraries - VSCODE - Jupyter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, documentation

I want to enable full documentation in Jupyter for VSCODE like Jupyter notebook has. I have researched a lot and tried all solutions suggested in different forums but can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Shortcut key - Jupyter Notebook SHTFT + TAB - Full documentation appearing and working (see picture)

[Jupyter Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMSJl.png)

Shortcut key - VSCODE / Jupyter - CTRL + SPACE - Does not work - Hovering works with full documentation (see picture)

[VSCODE NUMPY Full Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqSXt.png)

Shortcut key - VSCODE / Jupyter - CTRL + SPACE - Does not work for matplotlib- When I do hover over the command I get partial documentation (see picture)

[VSCODE matplotlib limited Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wY9P.png)

Can you please help with:

1. Shortcut key for JUPYTER in VSCODE (equivalent of Shift + TAB in jupyter notebook) - I already have Intellisense installed but CTRL + SPACE does not work for me. Is there any other shortcut key?
2. Why I get limited documentation in 1 library and full documentation in 1 library when I hover on the commands and how can I get full documentation for all libraries?

Here are the details for VSCODE

- Version: 1.62.3 (user setup)
- Commit:ccbaa2d27e38e5afa3e5c21c1c7bef4657064247
- Date:2021-11-17T08:11:14.551Z
- Electron: 13.5.2
- Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
- Node.js: 14.16.0 V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
- OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044

Here is the details for extensions I have installed on VSCODED

- Jupyter v2021.10.1101450599
- Jupyter Keymap v1.0.0
- Jupyter Notebook Renderes v1.0.4
- Pylance v2021.12.0
- Python v2021.11.1422169775
- Python v0.2.3

Python Environment details

- C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\python.exe
- 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 16:59:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
- sys.version_info(major=3, minor=9, micro=7, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Library version

- matplotlib version 3.4.3
- numpy version 1.20.3